# R plotly mesh3 coordinate lines through origin

Tags: r, plot, 3d, plotly

I try to plot cube and ball around it in 3D using plotly in R, type = "mesh3D". I was successful to get the plots right, however, can't get the coordinate lines to go through the origin, point (0,0,0). Any suggestions on how to do that? Code example:

```
library(misc3d)
library(plotly)
grid <- 100
f.1 <- function(x, y, z){
   (x^2+y^2+z^2)
}
f.2 <- function(x, y, z){
  abs(x)+abs(y)+abs(z)
}
x <- seq(-1, 1, length=grid) 
y <- seq(-1, 1, length=grid)
z <- seq(-1, 1, length=grid)
g <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y, z=z)
voxel.1 <- array(with(g, f.1(x,y,z)), c(grid,grid,grid))
voxel.2 <- array(with(g, f.2(x,y,z)), c(grid,grid,grid))
cont.1 <- computeContour3d(voxel.1, level=1, x=x, y=y, z=z)
idx.1 <- matrix(0:(nrow(cont.1)-1), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
cont.2 <- computeContour3d(voxel.2, level=1, x=x, y=y, z=z)
idx.2 <- matrix(0:(nrow(cont.2)-1), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
axx <- list(gridcolor="rgb(255,255,255)",zerolinecolor="rgb(0,0,0)")
axy <- list(gridcolor="rgb(255,255,255)",zerolinecolor="rgb(0,0,0)")
axz <- list(gridcolor="rgb(255,255,255)",zerolinecolor="rgb(0,0,0)")
plot.1 <- plot_ly(x = cont.1[,1], y = cont.1[,2], z = cont.1[,3],
           i = idx.1[,1], j = idx.1[,2], k = idx.1[,3],
           type = "mesh3d",opacity = 0.1,intensity=seq(0,1,length=4),showscale = FALSE,colors="red") %>%
add_trace(x = cont.2[,1], y = cont.2[,2], z = cont.2[,3],
         i = idx.2[,1], j = idx.2[,2], k = idx.2[,3],color="blue",
type="mesh3d",opacity=0.7,intensity=seq(0,1,length=4),
showscale=FALSE,inherit=FALSE) %>%
layout(scene = list(xaxis=axx,yaxis=axy,zaxis=axz))
plot.1
```

It plots zerolines through (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1), but cant get it to plot through (0,0,0).

Comment: I think this is not possible. A workaround is to set `zeroline = FALSE` in `(x|y|z)axis` and then to draw the lines manually.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is the only option I could think of too...